# Could not resolve host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com

Tags: php, paypal, dns, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to implement paypal pro credit card payment in php

I get following error no matter what i do.

- Could not resolve host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com

Its a DNS problem of computer I think. But are there any chances of CODE being wrong?

Comment: Your code isn't wrong, the website is offline.

Comment: If the error is "Could not resolve host", the problem is on your side. that name resolves fine (and the site works, over https)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.
It was about using proxy.
Had to configure proxy Host and port , username and password for it.
My sample code for that is as following.

```
 class classname
 {
 var $useProxy = TRUE;
 var $proxyHost = '192.135.2.1';//your host
 var $proxyPort = 0000;//your port

 public function(Params){

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxyHost.":".$this->proxyPort); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "user:password"); //username:pass 

 }
```

PS: or you could just use it without classes and functions.

Hope it helps!